# Change default option of installation profile

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

I've created a new installation profile name ABCD and it is showing on a "select an installation profile" Page

[image]

But it shows standard as a default option. How could i make ABCD as default.

I added hook_form_alter and hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in abcd.profile file but it's not working. As I've read in [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile) that bootstrap is fully loaded before reading .profile file but still form alter in not being executed in my case. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

In your profile .info file you can add the distribution name property in the following format:

```
distribution:
  name: ABCD
```

Notice: ADD this property but leave original top level "name" property in place.

This will totally omit  the  "Choose profile" step, and your profile will be auto selected for the entire process.

[image]